# Bt and generally UK caller id ordeal - retrieving caller id of an incoming call in C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, phone-call, telephony, modem

I am trying to develop a C# WinForm application in VS2015 that aims to act as a Call Management and Logging software. It's core feature, however, is the ability to detect an incoming call on a landline that can be from BT or any other landline provider in the UK such as VirginMedia.

I have enabled CLID on my landline and confirmed it's fully working using an old phone handset that has the Caller ID feature.

I eschew traditional phones so I intend to find an alternative that can be connected to/installed on a PC hence I will be able to establish a simple serial connection to the designated (fax)modem 
in order to perform AT Commands Set and/or get the Caller ID whenever the phone rings.

I have bought three modems so far as I know it can be a hit and miss and most forum discussions on the Internet made me understood that BT uses another standard for Caller ID handling and only very few modems are known to work with the standard made by the BT. Those are Zoom 3095 and US Robotics 5633

I have tried both of them with Putty and C# Serial Port Connectivity however around 70% of the time the Caller ID information is not displayed at all and all I get is RING RING

Caller id on BT is sent before the first ring which does work on my landline phone but not all the time on my modems!

I am wondering if anyone has had any similar problems in the past as understandably different standards are used such as Bellcore, DTMF, etc so my question could be question of those who are trying to develop a cross-country application as well.

Any advice is greatly appreciated as I sadly have no money left to keep buying random ancient modems anymore.

Answer (score 0):

A piece of advice for those who might end up wasting their time like me:

Do not waste your time capturing CID with Modems; It's not a reliable solution + it won't work globally.

Get yourself a USB caller id device that sends Incoming call data to the computer via an easy to use SDK ( I have found one for only £35 and it works!)